# Extracting Z coordinate in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, extract

I want to extract the Z coordinates from the line nodes. The data is there in the vector editor.

[image: example]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by extract? Do you want to extract the data to a CSV, do you want to extract the data from the line vertices to points?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in the z-coordinate of each point, you should convert the line into points. You can use for example the "Extract Nodes" tool in QGIS for this task. After that open the Field Calculator for the point layer, paste `z($geometry)` like in the image below and write the result in a field in the attribute table.

[image]